# How can we delete all records of a particular class using REST API in Parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

How can we delete all records of a particular class using REST API in Parse.com?
e.g., https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/DBCiZkQfhu
I can delete object using above URL but can't find how to delete all records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `batch` operations to do that. The documentation shows an example.

https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects-batch

Comment: Thank you Subin. I know I can use batch operations but it has limitation of 50 objects per request. What if I want to manipulate more than 50 objects at a time ?